# Scroll On Mouse Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm an interface designer new to development, and I've run into a snag with a side project I'm working on. I'd like to create a long, horizontally-scolling parallax scene. Users can use their mousewheel to scroll the view horizontally. (I'm currently using this JQuery plugin to help me accomplish this: http://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/)

Additionally, I'd like to ability for users to hover over a 20px gap on the left or right edge of their browser window to scroll the view in that direction for as long as they hover there. (As a reference, this interaction is based on a lot of MOBA games like LoL, Dota 2, or HOTS, where users can hold their cursors over an edge of the screen to pan around the map.)

I've found a sample script (shown below), but it doesn't accomplish exactly what I'm trying to do. In this example, the screen is divided in half vertically, and hovering in the top or bottom section scrolls the view up or down. As I mentioned above, I only want a 20px wide by 100% height of the screen area which a user can hover to scroll their view.

My current source:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
$("html, body").scrollTop(function(i, v) {
        var h = $(window).height();
        var y = e.clientY - h / 2;
        return v + y * 0.1;
    });
});
```

Any suggestions would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

First make 2 divs, one for the left and one for the right. Set their position to fixed in CSS and make them scroll the page while hovering over them.

This is what my JS test code looks like:

```
var offset = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.left').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    this.iid = setInterval(function() {
    offset += 300;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: offset
    }, 1);

  }, 10);
}).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
});


$('.right').bind('mouseenter', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  this.iid = setInterval(function() {
    offset -= 300;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offset
    }, 1);

  }, 10);
}).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
  });
});
```

Here is the full example:
https://jsfiddle.net/h596y5rs/1/